# Determine FilePath to Resource in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a CSV file in my Visual Stuido 2010 solution and I'm wondering how I can determine the absolute path to that CSV file. I need it to be dynamic as the path does change depending on where the project file is located on a User's filesystem.

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the CSV file is in the working directory of your application, you can get the absolute path using the [Path.GetFullPath Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx):

```
var result = Path.GetFullPath("file.csv");
// result == @"C:\Users\...Studio 2010\Projects\MyProject\bin\Debug\file.csv";
```

Answer (score 2):

A path can be either absolute or relative to some location (often the location of the executable). If you have a CSV file in your project you could set in its properties to be automatically copied to the output folder (`Copy to Output Directory: Copy always`) and in your application use relative path:

```
using (var csv = File.OpenRead("test.csv"))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Path.GetFullPath Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx#Y0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
string exedir = Path.GetDirectory(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

to get main exe dir.
Then you could append what you like. E.g.

```
csv_path = Path.Combine(exedir, "my_csv_file.csv")
```

or

```
csv_path = Path.Combine(exedir, @"subdir1\subdir2\my_csv_file.csv")
```